# Azure Cosmos: changeFeedProcessor: Error: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation

Tags: java, database, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying the sample application for changeFeedProcessor SDK for Azure-Cosmos.

GIT link of repo:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-changefeedprocessor-java

have configured all the required properties as below

COSMOSDB_ENDPOINT={hostandport}

COSMOSDB_SECRET={secretKey}

COSMOSDB_DATABASE={DBName}

COSMOSDB_COLLECTION={CollectionName}

COSMOSDB_AUX_COLLECTION={AuxCollectionName}

COSMOSDB_LEASE_COLLECTION={LeaseCollectionName}

and provided the hostname in sample.java

In the method DocumentLeaseServiceManager.initialize(),
documentServices.createDocument() operation is success, while documentServices.deleteDocument() fails with the below error

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PartitionKey value must be
>   supplied for this operation. at
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.addPartitionKeyInformation(DocumentClient.java:3346)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.deleteDocument(DocumentClient.java:1047)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.changefeedprocessor.services.DocumentServices.deleteDocument(DocumentServices.java:248)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.changefeedprocessor.internal.documentleasestore.DocumentServiceLeaseManager.initialize(DocumentServiceLeaseManager.java:116)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.changefeedprocessor.ChangeFeedEventHost.initializeIntegrations(ChangeFeedEventHost.java:165)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.changefeedprocessor.ChangeFeedEventHost.start(ChangeFeedEventHost.java:143)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.changefeedprocessor.ChangeFeedEventHost.lambda$registerObserverFactory$0(ChangeFeedEventHost.java:133)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Would really appreciate a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That version of the Change Feed Processor seems rather old. It could be possible that is not compatible with partitioned Lease containers. If your Lease collection is partitioned (Partition Key should be `/id`), try the updated Change Feed Processor that is already part of the Java SDK.

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/tree/v3

Example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/tree/v3/examples/src/main/java/com/azure/data/cosmos/examples/ChangeFeed

Comment: Thanks Matias, this one works well. Solved my problem.

Comment: Btw....I need to observe changeFeed from all the containers of a Database. Is there a way to do that without creating separate instances to observe separate containers?

Comment: No, Change Feed is only available at the container level.